# Escaping < and > with grep

Tags: grep

I'm loosing something here. If I have a file with contents:

```
foo
<foo>
```

And I do `grep "\<foo\>" file_name` shouldn't it match only the second line? I'm also matching the first.

I'm not very good with grep so I'm probably messing things up.

Comment: I don't think you need to escape them. Try this:
grep "<foo>"

Comment: Apparently I was over thinking this. Ok. So why escaping them makes grep ignore them in text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping them activates their meta-character properties and turns them into word boundaries in GNU grep:

```
$ grep 'foo' file
foo
<foo>
foobar

$ grep '\<foo\>' file
foo
<foo>
```

The 2nd grep above isn't looking for the string `<foo>`, it's looking for the string `foo` NOT preceded or succeeded immediately by word-constituent characters.

In general it's not safe to escape characters without knowing exactly what it means to do so. Here's another example:

```
$ printf 'aa\na{2}b\n'
aa
a{2}b
$ printf 'aa\na{2}b\n' | grep 'a{2}'
a{2}b
$ printf 'aa\na{2}b\n' | grep 'a\{2\}'
aa
```

The above `\{..\}` is activating their meta character properites as regexp interval delimiters.